# How to locate an object within an array and replace it with a new object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like so:

```
[
  {color: "blue"}, 
  {color: "red", size: "large"}, 
  {color: "green", size: "medium"}
]
```

Showing this how can I:

1. Find the object with a color of `green`
2. Replace that object with `{color: "green", size: "x-large"}`

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `find` and then modify the found object.

```js
var array = [{color: "blue"}, {color: "red", size: "large"}, {color: "green", size: "medium"}],
    found = array.find(({color}) => color === 'green');

if (found) found.size = 'x-large';

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) array it will return array.

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const arr= [
  {color: "blue"}, 
  {color: "red", size: "large"}, 
  {color: "green", size: "medium"}
];


let result = arr.map(obj=>{
 return obj.color=='green'? {color: "green", size: "x-large"}:obj;
})

console.log(result)
```

you can also use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [{
  color: "blue"
}, {
  color: "red",
  size: "large"
}, {
  color: "green",
  size: "medium"
}];

let result = arr.find(v => v.color == 'green');

if (result) {
  result.size = 'x-large';
}
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

If need to replace in the existing object you can use forEach and check for the color, else if need to return a new array you can use map function

```js
var oldObj = [{
    color: "blue"
  },
  {
    color: "red",
    size: "large"
  },
  {
    color: "green",
    size: "medium"
  }
]
oldObj.forEach(function(item) {
  if (item.color === 'green') {
    item.size = 'x-medium';
  }
});
console.log(oldObj)
```